# do a repetitive call of Task.Factory.StartNew with many function in a function

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to do something special. that I can't explain with a description but with an example.
I have a call many function with multithread (Task.Factory.StartNew) but it's take many lines and I would to automatise this in one function with only 1 line.
from this :

```
Dictionary<string, Task> tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
int func1Result;
string func2Result;
List<int> func3Result;
tasks.Add("func1", Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        func1Result = func1(var1, var2);
    }));
……………
tasks.Add("func2", Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        func2Result = func2(var3, var4);
    }));
……………
tasks.Add("func3", Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        func3Result = func3(var5, var6);
    }));
```

to something like this :

```
Dictionary<string, Task> tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
int func1Result;
string func2Result;
List<int> func3Result;
AddMultiTask(tasks, "func1", func1Result, func1(var1, var2));
OR
AddMultiTask(tasks, "func1", func1Result, func1, new List<dynamic> {var1, var2});
```

Is this possible?

sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a local function so that it looks a bit cleaner:

```
Dictionary<string, Task> tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

void AddTask(string name, Action body)
   => tasks.Add(name, Task.Factory.StartNew(body));

AddTask("func1", () => func1());
AddTask("func2", () => func2());
...
```

When you are ready to read the results you can pull them from the dictionary: `tasks["func1"].Result`.